# Need the exact definition of divergence to minus infinity using quantifiers

Tags: real-analysis

Is the definition of a sequence diverging to minus infinity:

for all $H<0$ there exists $n_0$ contained in the natural set such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $s_n \leq H$ 
or is it,
for all $H>0$ there exists $n_0$ contained in the natural set such that for all $n\geq n_0$,$s_n \leq -H$.

or are both these statements the same?

Comment: You should write this out with mathematical symbols. Its terrible to read as is.

Comment: $\lim_n s_n=-\infty$ iff for all reals $M$ there is an $N$ such that for all naturals $n\ge N$, we have $s_n<M$.

Comment: (You can add that $N\in\mathbb N$ if you want, it does not matter. You can also add that $M<0$ if you want (this is your first version). Again, it does not matter, the resulting statement is equivalent, and the equivalence is straightforward. Similarly, your second statement is obviously equivalent to the first.

Comment: (The point is, how precisely we write this, which of the three versions we use, is a matter of taste, not of mathematics. There is no central mathematical authority that decides which of these versions constitutes the "exact definition".)

Comment: Finally, a word on how you wrote the statement. Do not say "the natural set". Say instead "the set of natural numbers" or even "the set of naturals" or "the naturals". Also, "contained in" is for subsets, the relation you want is membership, which you say "belongs to". But, really, rather than "there exists $n_0$ that belongs to the naturals", simply say "there is a natural $n_0$".